# How to find elements that are out of page

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm trying to repair a slideout javascript menu. The problem is, that the 3rd level sub-menu doesn't show although it should. I am sure it has something to do with wrong positioning and the element is showing somewhere outside the page.

Now my question is: is there a browser extension, or some other way to outline an element that is beyond borders of the page?

Thanks!

EDIT: Okay that's weird.. according to the coords it seems to be in the correct position, it also has proper dimensions, is visible and yet I can't see it.. am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (in Firefox) or Chrome Developer console (CTRL+SHIFT+C) (in Chrome), locate your menu on html tab and checkout the *computed styles* for that element to see where is it. You can also type any styles you like and see how it affects your menu.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) allows you to inspect the DOM; You can use the HTML tab to find your missing element. When you click on the element, Firebug will highlight it and overlay guides showing you where it is. It will also give you positioning information in the Layout tab on the right, and you can reposition the element by changing its style using the Style tab.

Chrome developer tools already has this built in; Go to Settings->Tools->Developer Tools (or use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl-Shift-I`) to activate it. It's very similar to Firebug.